# Create a new sheet with a spreadsheet Google Sheets API

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets

I am using the google sheets API, I am able to create a new spreadsheet but when it comes to creating a new sheet within the spreadsheet I receive this error:

> "error: :3:1: error: expected member name or constructor call after type name
>   Error
>   "

my code

```
let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()

let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()

    let properties = GTLRSheets_SheetProperties.init()
    properties.title = "testingNewSheet"
    properties.index = 0
    properties.sheetId = 12345

    let sheetRequest = GTLRSheets_AddSheetRequest.init()
    sheetRequest.properties = properties

    request.addSheet = sheetRequest

    batchUpdate.requests = [request]

    let createQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: "mySpreadsheetID")

    service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, NSError) in

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error probably has to do with the usage of NSError (a class name), instead of assigning your own variable name.

So, this would be more appropriate:

```
service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, error) in
    // do stuff here
}
```